# How to shrink the size of an image when loading it in

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to display images at 16x16. But when I do that using css, example:(width:16px;), the image is still loaded at its original size which slows the time it takes to load the page. I was wondering if there is a way to only load the image as 16x16 instead of like 2000x2000, not just change the width and height of the image and also not changing the actual size of the image with php.

Thanks
Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to have two images. The full sized one and a thumbnail sized one. You should sparingly use CSS to scale the size of the image, most of the time you should be resizing the image to the size you want. When you have a 2000x2000 sized image and use CSS to make it 16x16 you are still loading the 2000x2000 sized image. Its still taking up the same amount of bandwidth regardless of how it renders in the users browser. So by creating the thumbnail image your ar drastically decreasing the size and time it takes to load in the user's browser.

Answer (score 4):

Erm... no?

What you're asking is like asking if you can take a 500-page essay and take every 1000th letter without counting through the whole document.

The only real way is for the image to be 16x16 in the first place.

Comment: Okay thanks, I wasn't sure because i know that you can preload an image with javascript and there you can tell it what size the image was so I wasn't sure if that actually shrank the image or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way a client could resize or ocmpress an image for performance benefits. If the client could compress an image it would *still* have to download the full-sized original, defeating the purpose compressing.

So, the only way to get the image at 16x16 is either make it that size, or use a server-side script to resize your images.